# How to run circle ci only on PR and not on merge.?

Tags: circleci

Is there any way to run circle ci build only when the pr raised to a specific branch and not on when merged to the branch.

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason why you'd like not to run workflows when a PR is merged?

There are a few ways how to do this:

- use [dynamic config](https://circleci.com/docs/dynamic-config/) to evaluate whether `$CIRCLE_PULL_REQUEST` exists, then skip the subsequent execution
- (Assuming you're using GitHub) - trigger the CircleCI pipeline from a GitHub Action. There you can set up exactly which events you'd like to intercept. Then you can also pass a [pipeline variable](https://circleci.com/docs/pipeline-variables/) to that pipeline. Maybe this blog post can help:
  https://ruarfff.com/posts/circleci-pr-only